# Download Link to JSON2 on Github broken

Tags: javascript, json

Need to download the JSON2 files but https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js download seems broken. After clicking download it waits long and later shows Bad Gateway.May be its down temporary or might be specific to me.

Any other safer links to download this?

Comment: The same happens for me, currently.  You could just clone the repository if you have Git installed.

Comment: Failing that, there's only five files; downloading them individually shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is clone this project by git:

```
git clone git://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.git
```

But projects has only 5 files. You can download it manually: open sources and copy content through clipboard.

Edited: replace "pull" to "clone". Pull will work if you alredy setupped project to update sources.

Edited2: "Save As" is not works =( it downloads a html page, not file source.

Comment: I clicked on the raw button on GitHub and created a js file from it.

Comment: You can just click on the Zip button to download the entire [repository](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/)